# How do I get the an object by name and highest timestamp

Tags: django, django-models

I want to fetch the transaction belonging to external_id=1 and has the highest timestamp.

I have tried this

```
max_rating = Transaction.objects.aggregate(organisation_id_from_partner=organisation_id, highest_timestamp=Max('timestamp'))
```

But I get `TypeError: QuerySet.aggregate() received non-expression(s): 1.`

Answer (score 2):

Inside aggregate, you can only write Aggregate function.
Try this

```
max_rating = Transaction.objects.filter(organisation_id_from_partner=organisation_id).order_by('-timestamp').first()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can slightly shorten [the answer by @shafik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4751726/shafik) by using [**`.latest(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest):

```
max_rating = Transaction.objects.filter(
    organisation_id_from_partner=organisation_id
).latest('timestamp')
```